# Using Lync 2013 as Client and Jabber Backend

Tags: xmpp, lync-2013

Cisco Jabber is being deployed in my ORG.
I am interested in knowing if Lync 2013 can be used as a Client `(No Lync Server is available)`

Earlier i have used Lync 2013 as client and MS Communicator Server (2007) as back-end through some registry changes.

I know `XMPP gateway` is required for Lync 2013 Server for Inter communication with Cisco Unified communication.

Any pointers in this direction will be helpful

Comment: I don't feel savvy enough to expand it into an answer, but:
1. It is possible to a certain extent. Some components are interoperable.
2. It is not a very good idea, unless you really have to.

What functionality do you intend to share?

Comment: I am looking to just use the IM Feature... nothing more

Answer (score 1):

Lync client cannot work as an XMPP client. XMPP supports in Lync is only relating to gateway. It means that users of a Lync Server can talk with users of an XMPP server. However, it does not mean you can use Lync client to connect directly to an XMPP server.

Comment: Ohh, So its kinda limitation of Lync, but i heard lync is extensible, do you konw any plugin that lync client can install that lets it talk directly to XMPP Server :)

Comment: No idea, never heard of such plugin.

Comment: Wouldn't this be enough? Gateway - if you just plan to use IM.